# User Management Web API application for custom Azure AD Tenant

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to develop a RESTful API to manage users in a custom Azure AD tenant. User management includes the following *(the AAD tenant will contain predefined groups)*:

- Create Users
- Delete Users
- Assign User to Group(s)
- Remove User from Group(s)
- Reset User Password

I am confused about how to set up the application registration and hoping to get direction based on the following:

1. The REST API application must be secured by Azure AD, so only designated admin users can access and use the API. Does that require the REST API application to be registered in the AAD Tenant where permissions to use the API and let the API access user profile (and group membership) is set?
2. The REST API is essentially a client of the Microsoft Graph API, which I envision facilitates the above operations requested by an admin user. Does that require a separate application registration, or can the same registration be used to provide necessary permissions?
3. Do I need the ADAL library in this situation?

Comment: For question 1 and 2, Do you want to make your application to be Mulit-tenant? E.g. With this API, it can do operation with 2 tenants.

Comment: There is no multi tenant requirement as of now. Everything is in the context of a single organization.

Comment: So, it's clear that you should register your API in the AAD tenant.One application registration can add multi permissions to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that require the REST API application to be registered in the AAD
>   Tenant where permissions to use the API and let the API access user
>   profile (and group membership) is set?

Of course,you the Rest API app should be registered in the AAD.

> Does that require a separate application registration, or can the same
>   registration be used to provide necessary permissions?

You can just need to register one app and you can assign mulitple permissions to it. Also you can add different roles to the app for different access scope to your API.Although, Your REST API is just like a client for the Microsoft Graph API, You can just assign the permssions to it by Applicaiton registration.So,you can just the Microsoft Graph by sepcify the resource in the HTTP request.

> Do I need the ADAL library in this situation?

Yes, you need. For your web API, if you use AAD v1 ednpoint, you can just use ADAL to validate the JWT token and do some neccessary operations.

Comment: I'm not very clear about your scenario. E.g What kind of client do you use to call the API, Native App or SPA or Web app. Generally, API is just like a Web App, which should also be reigstered in AAD and it also need to validate the token by using ADAL.

Comment: I have an App Service for a RESTful API, which is registered in the Azure AD tenant and uses ADAL to facilitate a "headless" login for an iOS native app. The iOS app receives an access token to make subsequent API calls. This app registration has Windows Azure Active Directory with _Sign and Reader User Profile_ permission set under Delegated Permissions. In order to create users and assign to groups, as well as set application-specific roles, I started to wonder if I needed a second app registration, or if I should add Microsoft Graph API and set permissions to the existing registration..

Comment: The web application corresponding to the RESTful API is registered in Azure AD as a Native app. It seems that is the only way to use ADAL4J if I want the user to get an access token _without_ encountering the Azure login page. If so, that is a blocker, because I was counting on setting up application roles in the enterprise app registration, which appears to be supported only for Web/API type app registrations. The blade in Azure does not display any such options for a native app registration. Can you please verify if this is by design?

Comment: Hi,@WebUser . I think you should register both a Native App and Web API in AAD. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows#mobile-and-native-apps) and this [Sample](https://github.com/azureadquickstarts/nativeclient-ios)

Comment: I ended up creating a "dummy" Web API application registration in Azure AD just so I could generate a client secret, which enabled me to get an application-level access token that enabled the code to create users. I am unable to delete a user or reset the password for a user (get error response _insufficient privileges_). Upon more reading, I found that those are not part of application level permissions. But I don't see the necessary permissions in delegated permissions either, in the Web App/API app registration.